# On new iPad, "notify me" button does not function in Find My Friends

Tags: apns, ios, geolocation, icloud

I want to use the new notify me feature in find my friends, so I can know when they arrive at XX or leave from YY.

I have two friends set up in Find my Friends.

I have upgraded to the new iOS 6. This is a new iPad.

When I am in the find my friends app, I can see the "notify me" button, but it is greyed out slightly and pressing it does not work. Weirdly, if I hold my finger down on it, the classic spinning clock flower icon thing briefly spins as if it started to try something.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you allow Find My Friends to send push notifications? (Settings > Notifications > Not In Notification Center)

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with your friends and not your device. I haven't nailed down exactly why some of my friends allow me to set geo-fenced alerts and others do not.

I don't see a setting to disable it other than the **Show Geofence Alerts From:** which implies that I can restrict those I see - not those I share with.

Sorry I can't offer a perfect fix, but this is something on the account / friend's side of things and not a switch you can control on your device.